# ¿Cómo ingreso una cadena por teclado en C++?

Tags: c++

Cuando ingreso la cantidad de cursos para llenar los datos de los alumnos y quiero ingresar el nombre, me lo salta, ¿por qué sucede esto? Tampoco sé si está bien la comparación del `while` para que cuando ingrese la palabra "fin" salga del ciclo...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   char nombre[50];
    int edad,n;
    cout<<"ingrese cantidad de cursos"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"ingrese el nombre:"<<endl;
        cin.getline(nombre,sizeof(nombre));
        while(nombre!="fin"){
        cout<<"ingrese la edad del alumno:"<<endl;
        cin>>edad;
        cout<<"ingrese el nombre:"<<endl;
        cin.getline(nombre,sizeof(nombre));
        }
    }
    cout<<nombre<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tambien estoy tratando de aprender a ingresar una cadena de caracteres en C++. Recibiste respuesta?

Lo unico que te puedo decir es que la comparacion del while está mal, ya que C++ no permite que se usen los operadores para comparar caracteres. Para hacerlo correctamente, deberias usar funciones disponibles en en la biblioteca <string.h>.
la funcion strcmp recibe las dos cadenas como parametro y devuelve un 0 si son iguales.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/346797)